# Multiple selection of nodes in d3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have got the following code snippet which works fine for single selection(and deselection). Could anyone help me out to extend this code so that one could make multiple selections(and deselect the node when clicking on the same node again)?

```
function click(d){

        if(!selected){

            selected = d3.select(this);
            selected.style('stroke', 'red')
            userSelect=d.user_ids;
            console.log(userSelect);
            createNewSVG(userSelect);

        }

        else if(selected[0][0] == d3.select(this)[0][0]){

            selected.style('stroke', 'white');
            selected = undefined;
            removeSVG();
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need something like

```
function click(d){
    d3.select(this).classed("selected", !d3.select(this).classed("selected"));
    d3.selectAll("foo").style("stroke", "white");
    d3.selectAll(".selected").style('stroke', 'red');
}
```

This will add a class `selected` to all selected things, which you can use to select and modify them with D3.

Comment: How can I store up the data bound to the selected nodes in an array?

Comment: `d3.selectAll(".selected").data()`

Comment: Hi again, your answer for multiple selection works but there seems to be some problem with deselection. That part seems to not work,i.e. there is no change in stroke color from red to white.

Comment: You'll have to change `foo` in my code to whatever your elements are.

Comment: Now I realized, the dot was missing in front of foo.